# Java how to add child class to an array

Tags: java, arrays

at the moment, I am wondering if there is a way to add a child class object to a parent class array.

I have code that follows the generic line of:

```
    public abstract class Parent {  
        ...
    }

    public class Child extends Parent {
        ...
    }
```

And I have an array that follows along the lines of:

```
Parent[] array = new Parent[number];
```

I want to be able to add my child objects to this array like:

```
array[0] = new Child();
```

However whenever I do this, I get an error message saying that they are incompatible types. I know this can be achieved in `ArrayList` but I want to see if it is possible in the format above. Is there a way to achieve this without ArrayList?

Comment: This doesn't compile `Parent[] array = new Parent[];`  I suspect your code is different which is the reason it doesn't compile.

Comment: Ahh okay, I come from a C# background and quite new to Java. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I edited the number in the array if that is what you are talking about.

Comment: @Brian It must work then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code compiles without error:

```
public abstract class Parent {

  private static class Child extends Parent {}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Parent[] array = new Parent[1];
    array[0] = new Child();
  }
}
```

This is very similar to the code in your question. So perhaps compare your code with mine and spot the difference?

In Java (and in most/all OO languages), this polymorphic behaviour is standard and completely correct.

Comment: I feel so foolish, I added a completely different class which is named similarly to the child class. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this:

```
    enter codepublic abstract class Parent {

  private static class Child extends Parent {}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Parent[] array = new Parent[1];
    Parent child = new Child();
    array[0] = child;
  }
} here
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put size of array when creating, everything works with it :)

`Parent[] array = new Parent[5];`
`array[0] = new Child();`